# Apache Ignite mapping Instant in 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

When upgrading from Ignite 2.6.0 to 2.7.0 I get exception when loading data to cache via cache loading API. There is only one version of h2 on classpath and that is 1.4.197 (I have also upgraded h2 from 1.4.196 to 1.4.197). Btw this is Springboot project.

How do I fix this so I can upgrade Ignite from 2.6.0 to 2.7.0?

It seems Java Instant is resolved to SQL type 24 but Ignite does not support that.

I have a Ignite entity with field of type Instant like this:

```
@QuerySqlField(index = true, notNull = true, orderedGroups = {
            @QuerySqlField.Group(name = "FIXTURE_START", order = 1),
            @QuerySqlField.Group(name = "FIXTURE_STATE_START", order = 2)})
    private Instant start;
```

And when I try to load entitities via cache loading API:

```
public abstract class AbstractIgniteCacheJdbcAdapter<ID, ENTITY> extends CacheStoreAdapter<ID, ENTITY> implements Serializable
    @Override
    public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<ID, ENTITY> clo, Object... args) {
        try {
            List<ENTITY> entities = getEntities();
            entities.forEach(e -> clo.apply(e.getKey(), e));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CacheLoaderException("Failed to load values from cache store.", e);
        }
    }
```

I get and exception:

```
org.h2.message.DbException: Obecná chyba: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to wrap value[type=24, value=2018-01-01T10:00:00Z]"
General error: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to wrap value[type=24, value=2018-01-01T10:00:00Z]" [50000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:307)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.getValue0(GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.java:138)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.getValue(GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.java:113)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.toString(GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.java:201)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.doPut(BPlusTree.java:2285)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.putx(BPlusTree.java:2232)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.database.H2TreeIndex.putx(H2TreeIndex.java:299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table.addToIndex(GridH2Table.java:546)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table.update(GridH2Table.java:479)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.store(IgniteH2Indexing.java:768)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.store(GridQueryProcessor.java:1905)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.store(GridCacheQueryManager.java:404)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.finishUpdate(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:2633)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke0(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1646)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1621)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.invoke(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:428)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.storeValue(GridCacheMapEntry.java:4248)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.initialValue(GridCacheMapEntry.java:3391)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheEntryEx.initialValue(GridCacheEntryEx.java:766)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.loadEntry(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:684)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.access$600(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:104)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$5.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:634)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter$5.apply(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:630)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter$3.apply(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:536)
    at cz.ifortuna.betofferservice.data.legacy.ignite_adapter.AbstractIgniteCacheJdbcAdapter.lambda$loadCache$67(AbstractIgniteCacheJdbcAdapter.java:51)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at cz.ifortuna.betofferservice.data.legacy.ignite_adapter.AbstractIgniteCacheJdbcAdapter.loadCache(AbstractIgniteCacheJdbcAdapter.java:51)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.loadCache(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:520)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheAdapter.localLoadCache(GridDhtCacheAdapter.java:630)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.localLoadCache(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:222)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5676)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5725)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$TopologyVersionAwareJob.execute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6361)
    at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeJobAdapter.call(ComputeJobAdapter.java:132)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1855)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:568)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6816)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:562)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:491)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1125)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.sendRequest(GridTaskWorker.java:1420)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.processMappedJobs(GridTaskWorker.java:666)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:538)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:764)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:452)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:449)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:420)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor.callAsync(GridClosureProcessor.java:404)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.globalLoadCacheAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:3869)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.loadCacheAsync(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.loadCacheAsync(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:287)
    at cz.ifortuna.betofferservice.data.repository.ignite.IgniteRepositoryBase.initCache(IgniteRepositoryBase.java:127)
    at cz.ifortuna.betofferservice.service.RepositoryManager.lambda$null$45(RepositoryManager.java:74)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
    at cz.ifortuna.betofferservice.service.RepositoryManager.lambda$null$46(RepositoryManager.java:74)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1280)
    at cz.ifortuna.betofferservice.service.RepositoryManager.lambda$init$47(RepositoryManager.java:70)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1280)
    at cz.ifortuna.betofferservice.service.RepositoryManager.init(RepositoryManager.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1691)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:129)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:141)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:196)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:185)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:188)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Obecná chyba: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to wrap value[type=24, value=2018-01-01T10:00:00Z]"
General error: "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to wrap value[type=24, value=2018-01-01T10:00:00Z]" [50000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    ... 168 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to wrap value[type=24, value=2018-01-01T10:00:00Z]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2RowDescriptor.wrap(GridH2RowDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.getValue0(GridH2KeyValueRowOnheap.java:135)
    ... 165 common frames omitted
```

Comment: If I use java.sql.Date instead if Timestamp, I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try to replace `Instant` type by `java.sql.Timestamp`?

Comment: Yes I did and I get same error. But I have found that `LocalDateTime` works.

Answer (score 0):

you can describe your Instant field in the schema as `schemaFields.put("instantField", Object.class.getName())` instead of `schemaFields.put("instantField", Instant.class.getName())` and use binary cache via `cache.withKeepBinary()`. It works for me.